# Activating javascript by slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, bjqs

I have several maps that are generated by javascript files. That means that each map is generated by a single javascript file. Now I want to include a slider into my html file that lets me slide through the maps. I am using Basic jQuery Slider as the source of my slider.  
My problem is that the linked javascript files are always activated which results in all of the maps being displayed at the same time. How can I achieve that there is only one map active at the same time?
My code so far:

```
  <!--  Outer wrapper for presentation only, this can be anything you like -->
  <div id="banner-fade">

    <!-- start Basic Jquery Slider -->
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li><script src="js/Map1.js"></script></li>
      <li><script src="js/Map2.js"></script></li>
      <li><script src="js/Map3.js"></script></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end Basic jQuery Slider -->

  </div>
  <!-- End outer wrapper -->

  <script class="secret-source">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
        height      : 2000,
        width       : 2000,
        responsive  : true
      });

    });
  </script>

  </div>
```

Each one of the maps looks something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/CwiFnNmfIleo5zZ6BseW?p=preview

Comment: you cannot mix HTML and JS like this  <li><script src="js/Map1.js"></script></li>, instead, your Map1.js should have logic to append whatever DOM elements it produces to the first LI element, and so on

Comment: I just added the code for the map. I already thought about changing the map dynamically depending on its input values and changing the values with a slider within the js, but I thought that producing several seperate maps would be easier because the pies and the choropleth should be updated simultaneously.